# missing value imputation for non-equi-spaced gaps using timestamp using R

Tags: r, timestamp, imputation

I have a dataframe with two colums (one contains a timestamp and the other a specific value).

The gaps between the timestamps are not equi-spaced but are approximately the same length (1000 ms +/- 15%).

Every now and then a timestamp + value is missing resulting in a timestamp-difference of approx 2*(previous  difference).

Is there a way to find those gaps and just add an NA row to later fill it with imputated values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(id = as.character(1:20), t =  seq(1000, 20000, by = 1000) + runif(20, -15, 15), x = rnorm(20)) %>% 
  filter(!(id %in% c(3, 7, 9)))

df



df <- df %>% mutate(delta_t = t - lag(t),
              mean_t = (t + lag(t))/2) %>% 
  filter(delta_t > 1015 | delta_t < 985 ) %>% 
  mutate(t = mean_t, x = NA) %>% 
  select(id, t, x) %>% 
  bind_rows(df) %>% 
  arrange(t)

df
```

The id column is purely so that you can easily see that I've taken out three values in constructing the dummy data